# mysql sql id < 75 not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a feed in my website where user can "follow" other and see what he post.

so I have this select:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
WHERE user IN (
    < 75
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

so it get who patrick follow in table following and this people posts.
my problem is in ID < 75
mysql is ignoring this id<75 and always get the last posts id. this id 75 is important because ajax will send the last post load to do a correct pagination. first select posts id <75, id<70, id<65... but its not working.

what can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must make `()` arround the or statement:

```
select * from posts where (user in (select following from following where user ='patrick') or user='patrick') and id < 75 order by id desc limit 5
```

If you do not do it, first `and`will evaluated and then `or`